# Group Concat mysql pierde el order BY

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo la siguiente Consulta SQL pero el order by del GROUP Concat en algunos resultados no tiene el orden esperado ya que quisiera que sea por la fecha como se muestra en la imagen de abajo.

```
SELECT objects.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(mvalues.value ORDER BY mvalues.value ASC SEPARATOR ", ") as value 
    FROM objects 
    JOIN metadata_values mvalues ON mvalues.idObject = objects.idObject 
    JOIN metadata_descriptors mdescriptor ON mvalues.idDescriptor = mdescriptor.idDescriptor 
   WHERE objectType = 'EMBED' 
     AND mdescriptor.name IN ('Year Created', 'Thumbnail Patch') 
   GROUP BY objects.idObject ORDER BY objects.title ASC`
```

Este seria el resultado obtenido de la columna que me interesa ordenar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es *el orden esperado*? ¿No será que los datos están mal, que tienen espacios en blanco o algo así?

Comment: el `GROUP_CONCAT` el alias que le distes es `value` no `title`

Comment: Esto es muy raro. Si tienes un GROUP BY, solo puedes meter en el select los valores del GROUP BY o datos agregados. ¿Qué hay en `objects.*`?

Comment: En objects tengo una informacion basica, id, nombre, descripcion, en cambio en values es donde tengo la informacion que quiero mostrar en una relacion de muchos a muchos. Voy a editar para mostrar un capture de como aparece el orden. asi tal cual con la consulta mostrada

Comment: El orden esta correcto, ya que no estas ordenando por el concat, si no por la columna title.

Comment: @Arielperez, **por favor [edit] la pregunta** describiendo los resultados esperados de la consulta. Los comentarios son temporales.

Comment: entonces deseas ordenar por tu columna **value** y no **tittle**

Comment: Yo quiero ordenar es lo que esta adentro de la columna value. El order title es el orden que se muestra los resultados.